# Regex to get comma within xml tags

Tags: regex

I am new to regex. I have an xml like

```
 <Root xmlns="rooter"><add>This is an example, test</add></Root>, 123, test, 8765
```

I want to find only comma which is within the xml tags

I have tried

```
<Root.*\,.*</Root>
```

and

```
<Root.*>(\,)
```

It return the xml tag but I want only comma and replace with other character.

I want to replace this comma with other character in atom text editor. If I replace it, it should be like

```
 <Root xmlns="rooter"><add>This is an example# test</add></Root>, 123, test, 8765
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: XML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will work if the text is the same format as you have defined above.

```
,(?=[^\/<]*<\/)
```

I have used *`look ahead`* here. You can check the link for more details.

> https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: This will not work for `blah, blah<tag>lkjrtk</tag>`

Comment: It is asked to capture comma within xml tag. As xml tag end with '</' so I have used '</ ' specifically. Your format does not belong to wanted format. So it will not work.

Comment: Your regex will replace comma **before** the tag (i.e. `blah, blah` in my example), this is **not** wanted. Just try it!

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my regex.

Comment: @CoderX, the updated regex seems to solve the op's issue. Cool!